# Reinstall windows - remove everything except two programs?

Tags: windows, reinstall, software-activation

After more than 5 years, it's time to reinstall my windows 10. Things that run in the background and that i don't longer need are slowing down my pc.

Now it's super easy to do in w10, but my problem is that i don't want to remove my TI nSpire CX CAS Math software for school and my lightroom foto editing software for which i have a perpetual license. I don't have the license key for the Math software. Lightroom is not that such of a problem, but that are the two programs that require a license key and aren't freeware.

Comment: Windows 10 official release date was 29 July 2015. Guess you had a preview version :-)

Comment: Why can't you just ask your school for another license key?

Answer (score -1):

Most educational software licenses are stored in a license file, quite often in the same directory as the application was installed. The licenses files can also be located in the programdata folder (c:\programdata) which is a hidden folder.

The third place to look for license information is in the registry. This can be daunting if you don't know where to look but most of the time the registry key containing license information (if there is one) is located at

HKLM/Software/Company/Appname/ and then a subkey which is sometimes called serial or cd key or license key or some alias.

My organisation uses Adobe CS3 which doesn't require the license key to install or run as its all built in but I have no experience with Lightroom itself. I would assume the never ending license will just work but you can test this by installing it on a different machine.

Hope this helps a bit!